# not getting class definition for exceptions from wsdl

Tags: vb.net, web-services, soap, wsdl

We want to talk to a client's web service. They gave us a `WSDL`. I could only import it into asp.net using the legacy import -- `Add > Service Reference > Advanced > Add Web Reference.` Trying to use the regular `Add > Service Reference` gave tons of errors. (I'm guessing that's because this was done with `soap 1.1` and not something newer, but I don't know. I've never done a lot with soap.)

The WSDL includes type definitions for all sorts of `SOAP` exceptions they might send. They're all in there defined as "`complex types`".

But when I import, none of these definitions show up. They don't come as the auto-complete drop down in Visual Studio, and if I type them in I get "no such class" errors. I'm looking in the same namespace where all the classes used in messages appear.

Am I looking in the wrong place? Do these just not show up?

Do I have to re-create these classes manually?

Update

You ask what the error was trying to import as an ordinary service reference. Here it is: (Note: Names changed because the client is very strict about disclosure of their proprietary code.)

> Reference.svcmap: Failed to generate code for the service reference
>   'foo'.  Cannot import wsdl:portType  Detail: An exception was thrown
>   while running a WSDL import extension:
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerMessageContractImporter 
>   Error: There was a problem loading the XSD documents provided: a
>   reference to a schema type with name 'GetFoo' and namespace
>   'http://example.com/foo/service/v2/' could not be resolved because the
>   type definition could not be found in the schema for targetNamespace
>   'http://example.com/foo/service/v2/'. Please check the XSD documents
>   provided and try again.  XPath to Error Source:
>   //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://example.com/foo/ws/v2/']/wsdl:portType[@name='FooPortType_v2']
>   Cannot import wsdl:binding  Detail: There was an error importing a
>   wsdl:portType that the wsdl:binding is dependent on.  XPath to
>   wsdl:portType:
>   //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://example.com/foo/ws/v2/']/wsdl:portType[@name='FooPortType_v2']
>   XPath to Error Source:
>   //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://example.com/foo/ws/v2/']/wsdl:binding[@name='FooBinding_v2']
>   Cannot import wsdl:port  Detail: There was an error importing a
>   wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is dependent on.  XPath to
>   wsdl:binding:
>   //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://example.com/foo/ws/v2/']/wsdl:binding[@name='FooBinding_v2']
>   XPath to Error Source:
>   //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://example.com/foo/ws/v2/']/wsdl:service[@name='FooService_v2']/wsdl:port[@name='FooPort_v2']    App_WebReferences/foo/

Note that the very same WSDL works if I import it using the legacy
method, so it's not simply an error in the WSDL. The thing is
complicated, as the WSDL has multiple levels of includes and imports,
complex types composed of other complex types, etc.

Maybe I'm asking the wrong question. Maybe the question should be: Why can I import this WSDL with the legacy import, but not with the current import?

Perhaps I should also note that I was trying to import by copying the WSDL into my app and then doing the Add Service by pointing to this WSDL file. At this time I don't yet have access to the real web site, but they gave me some documentation and the WSDLs.

Comment: You should create the proxy using the Add -> Service Reference and not as a web reference. WCF Serialization would determine if it needs to use the DataContractSerializer or XMLSerializer depending on the types. What kind of errors are you getting ?

Comment: @Agalo I've added the text of the error. If you know what causes this, I'd be overjoyed to hear it.